# Get top items of QSortFilterProxyModel in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, qsortfilterproxymodel

Currently, I'm trying to get five items from a `QSortFilterProxyModel` after I sort the model.

I tried to do this:

```
void setSourceModel(QAbstractItemModel* source) override
{
     QSortFilterProxyModel::setSourceModel(source);
     auto* model{sourceModel()};
     model->sort(1);
}
```

and then:

```
bool filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex& sourceParent) const override
{
     return sourceRow < 5;
}
```

But that didn't work. I get the first 5 items in the unsorted source model, instead of the first 5 items of the sorted model.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Probably, you are using a `QAbstractItemModel` that doesn't support sorting. Note that the base class implementation [`QAbstractItemModel::sort`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#sort) does nothing. So, it is up to the derived class to correctly implement it if desired.

Comment: And what does not work, exactly?

Comment: @m7913d Yes, if i use `QSortFilterProxyModel::sort(1)` it also doesn't work.

@Atmo I've changed the description, thanks!

Comment: Because you filter on the source row index. So, sorting the proxy doesn't help to obtain the first 5 sorted items. See Atmo's answer for a working solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated in the comments, not all models support sorting (The base implementation `QAbstractItemModel::sort` is documented to do nothing).

Of course, you can override `sort` for your source model. Hopefully, there are at least 2 solutions to solve your problem without bothering with it.

**1. Using more than 1 level of proxy model**:

Instances of `QSortFilterProxyModel` can sort data regardless of what their source model is.

1. We can change the implementation of `setSourceModel` so that instead of attaching `source` directly to `this`, we place another `QSortFilterProxyModel` in between.
2. That way, we guarantee `this->sourceModel()` supports sorting.

```cpp
void setSourceModel(QAbstractItemModel* source) override
{
    QSortFilterProxyModel* sortModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
    sortModel->setSourceModel(source);
    setSourceModel(sortModel);
    sortModel->sort(1);
}
bool filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex& sourceParent) const override
{
    return sourceRow < 5;
}
```

**2. With a `QIdentityProxyModel`**:

The above solution builds 3 layers of models:
`QSortFilterProxyModel` subclass (filter) **>** `QSortFilterProxyModel` (sort) **>** `QAbstractItemModel`.

Your filter criterion is a little bit special in the sense it does not use the `data` method from its source. Since this is the case, you may as well extend the definition of what we call filtering and implement the layers as:
`QIdentityProxyModel`  subclass (filter) **>** `QSortFilterProxyModel` (sort) **>** `QAbstractItemModel`.

Inheriting `QIdentityProxyModel` with the below methods should make your model a little bit faster, although the difference may not be visible at all:

```cpp
void setSourceModel(QAbstractItemModel* source) override
{
    QSortFilterProxyModel* sortModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
    sortModel->setSourceModel(source);
    setSourceModel(sortModel);
    sortModel->sort(1);
}
int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
{
    //Should parent be tested?
    //if (!parent.isValid())
    return 5;
}
```

This is probably all you need. To be safe, you may choose to add the `mapFromSource` / `mapSelectionFromSource` methods (and as a bonus, I also include `mapToSource` / `mapSelectionToSource` even though I really think those last 2 are not needed):

```cpp
QModelIndex mapFromSource(const QModelIndex &sourceIndex) const override
{
    if (sourceIndex.row() >= 5)
        return QModelIndex();
    return QIdentityProxyModel::mapFromSource(sourceIndex);
}
QItemSelection mapSelectionFromSource(const QItemSelection& selection) const
{
    QItemSelection proxySelection;
    for (auto selRange : selection) {
        QModelIndex topLeftIndex = selRange.topLeft();
        if (topLeftIndex.row() < 5) {
            QModelIndex bottomRightIndex = it->bottomRight();
            if (bottomRightIndex.row() < 5) {
                const QItemSelectionRange range(
                   QIdentityProxyModel::mapFromSource(topLeftIndex),
                   QIdentityProxyModel::mapFromSource(bottomRightIndex)
                );
                proxySelection.append(range);
            }
            else {
                const QItemSelectionRange range(
                   QIdentityProxyModel::mapFromSource(topLeftIndex),
                   QIdentityProxyModel::mapFromSource(bottomRightIndex.siblingAtRow(4))
                );
                proxySelection.append(range);
            }
        }
    }
    return proxySelection;
}


QModelIndex mapToSource(const QModelIndex &proxyIndex) const override
{
    if (proxyIndex.row() >= 5)
        return QModelIndex();
    return QIdentityProxyModel::mapToSource(proxyIndex);
}
QItemSelection mapSelectionToSource(const QItemSelection& selection) const
{
    QItemSelection sourceSelection;
    for (auto selRange : selection) {
        QModelIndex topLeftIndex = selRange.topLeft();
        if (topLeftIndex.row() < 5) {
            QModelIndex bottomRightIndex = it->bottomRight();
            if (bottomRightIndex.row() < 5) {
                const QItemSelectionRange range(
                   QIdentityProxyModel::mapToSource(topLeftIndex),
                   QIdentityProxyModel::mapToSource(bottomRightIndex)
                );
                sourceSelection.append(range);
            }
            else {
                const QItemSelectionRange range(
                   QIdentityProxyModel::mapToSource(topLeftIndex),
                   QIdentityProxyModel::mapToSource(bottomRightIndex.siblingAtRow(4))
                );
                sourceSelection.append(range);
            }
        }
    }
    return sourceSelection;
}
```